# given a URL in python, how can i check if URL has RSS feed?

Tags: python, rss

am trying to find a way to detect if a given URL has an RSS feed or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: CURL . check for the format as per the RSS 2.0 Specification. or check for the line <rss version="2.0">

Answer (score 6):

Each RSS have some format.

1. See what `Content-Type` the server returns for the given URL. However, this may not be specific and a server may not necessarily return the correct header.
2. Try to parse the content of the URL as `RSS` and see if it is successful - this is likely the only definitive proof that a given URL is a `RSS` feed.